# How to recover deleted usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css file in gnome 3.4?

Tags: gnome

I deleted `usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css` is there a way I can recover this file, I am not looking for recovery programs, just maybe a command that will regenerate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing would be to reinstall the package that file belongs to:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell-common
```

Comment: its already the latest version, how can I reinstall it

Comment: Add the ``--reinstall` option: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell-common`

Comment: right, forgot the `--reinstall` option. thanks florian :) i edited my post.